# blogdown::serve_site, error copying static files

Tags: r, hugo, blogdown

I am trying to build a website using `blogdown` in RStudio.

I chose "New Project", "New Directory", "Website using blogdown", picked a name for the directory and left all other options the default. As expected, a nice directory structure with examples got created.

However, when I run `serve_site()` I get two times the same error messages:

```
Error: Error copying static files: chtimes <mypath>\public\: Wrong Parameter.
```

and then

```
The system can not find the specified path.
```

(own translations, `<mypath>` is an existing path).

I suspected that some entries in `config.toml` need to be adjusted and placed two files `logo.png` and `favicon.ico` into the `static` directory. This did not help.

Then I thought maybe the `baseurl` entry needs a different value than `/`. However, `blogdown:::site_root()` returns the correct folder.

It seems not to be an RStudio / blogdown problem, since if I enter the command

```
hugo.exe -b / -D -F -d "public" --themesDir themes -t hugo-lithium
```

at the command prompt in the project directory, the same error is returned.

Any ideas are very appreciated...

(I am on Windows 10, using RStudio 1.3.1073, R 4.0.2, and Hugo 0.75.1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer [outside of Stackoverflow](https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/issues/6127). The problem seems to be that the folder is on an exFAT external drive. By adding --noTimes, everything works fine:

```
hugo.exe -b / -D -F -d "public" --themesDir themes -t hugo-lithium --noTimes
```

Another option, which works probably better for me, is to to specify `publishDir` in the `config.toml` as subdirectory of my Documents folder. The command then changes to

```
hugo.exe -D -F --themesDir themes -t hugo-lithium
```

and it works even within RStudio.

With **blogdown** >= v1.1, the `--noTimes` argument can be specified in:

```r
blogdown::hugo_build(args = "--noTimes")
```

You can also set it in the global option in your `.Rprofile`:

```r
options(blogdown.hugo.args = "--noTimes")
```

so you would only need to call `blogdown::hugo_build()`.